# Как инициализировать string в несколько строк?

Tags: c++

Как инициализировать string в несколько строк? Как-то делал, но не могу вспомнить ))
Должно быть две кавычки, примерно так:

```
string s = " qwerty
asdfgh
zxcvbn";
```

Comment: `string s = " qwerty\nasdfgh\nzxcvbn";` - это?

Comment: string s = R"( qwerty
asdfgh
zxcvbn)";

Comment: Всё нашёл, через R"(

Comment: Можно и так. Но очень некрасиво в плане форматирования :)